# Emoji Issue Android

Tags: android, emoji

[image]

When I click the first emoji it displayed like not an other emojis. Other emojis are displayed as welll. But the first one is displayed as wrong. Anyone Help me

Comment: Which Image library you use?

Answer (score 0):

The emoji on top is system unicode.
You selected emoji is a picture and your device has not this emoji unicode so it display wrong.